# css not rendering when loading page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I have created dozens of node.js apps with ejs front end framework, but I downloaded a free html template online, and I tried converting everything to the same format as I have in my other projects, but the css is off, it is not rendering everything in the right place.

Here's my `index.ejs` header file importing the css files:

```
   <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Site CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <!-- Responsive CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css">
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>
```

Here's my `index.js` file

```
 //importing packages
const {
    response
} = require("express");
var express = require("express");
const {
    render
} = require("ejs");


//initializing application
const app = express();
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use("/public/css/images", express.static("./public/css/images"));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(
    express.urlencoded({
        extended: true,
    })
);


//main request 
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index.ejs')
})


//DEFINING PORT AND LISTEN ON PORT 1801
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 1801;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log("APP LISTENING ON PORT:", PORT);
});
```

It renders the page, but the contents of the page are all messed up.

Here's the file structure screenshot:

[image: file structure]

Comment: Looks like you typed `style.css` instead of `styles.css`

Comment: @enucar that was actually just a stackoverflow typo, but thanks for noticing that haha

Comment: Hard refreshing doesn't change that?

Comment: @ShanerM13 nope... tried going private tabs, clearing cache, hard refresh all of it and nothing worked.

Comment: Did you intend to nest images inside CSS

Comment: I think based off what you said your file structure is your lookig in the incorrect place for your css can you please try the following: `./public/css/style.css`

Comment: @Bibberty yes, I always do that and It usually works...

Comment: @DylanAnlezark from my EJS file?

Comment: Ok, for my apps and static I only have this line `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`

Comment: yes similar to how you are accessing your images with `app.use("/public/css/images", express.static("./public/css/images"));` @Gianluca

Comment: From there you should be using `/css/styles.css`

Comment: @DylanAnlezark tried that, still nothing changed

Comment: @Bibberty yea so I did play around with all those lines to try what you said you use... still the same results :(

Comment: @Gianluca Im still convinced you just aren't using the correct path is there any chance we can get a screenshot of your file structure to make sure, the way it is formatted in the question makes it hard to read :)

Comment: @DylanAnlezark just updated my question to include the ss :)

Comment: @DylanAnlezark It works from my html file, if I use the local path file://.... then it works, but running localhost doesn't... strange?

Comment: @Gianluca could you please try the following and let me know if it is successful:
`../public/css/images`

Comment: @DylanAnlezark unfortunately I got the same thing.

Comment: sorry I had a typo in the above comment should have been `../public/css/styles.css`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230521/discussion-between-dylan-anlezark-and-gianluca).